# Get a list of fields in MongoDB Document?

Tags: java, list, mongodb, dbobject

Is it possible to get a list of all the fields in a DBObject? I have searched through the documentation and can't find anything. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? You can get all the keys with keySet() and all the values with get(key). A list of keys or values is not useful in logical context since the key/value -pairs shouldn't be in any particular order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5.2/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) implements the java.util.Map interface.  So, you can use the Map's keySet() method to get the list of keys (or "fields").